# Reading a few messed up files in Python

Tags: python, io

I wrote a small parsing function for files of type [.off](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/off/off.html). In this file format, the first line should just be the letters "OFF" and the second line should be 3 numbers dictating the size of the rest of the file.

I have thousands of these files. In a small, random percentage of these files, though, the first two lines are incorrectly concatenated (not sure why). Short of iterating using `readline()` rather than `readlines()`, I can't seem to come up with a way to address this when reading.

Please also assume it is also impractical to change all the files (I've considered trying a bash script, but it's a public dataset then I may continue to pull from in the future).

Any suggestions how to address these corrupted header lines?

Here is my current parsing function:

```
import numpy as np
def off_vertex_parser(self, path_to_off_file):
    print path_to_off_file
    # Read the OFF file
    with open(path_to_off_file, 'r') as f:
        contents = f.readlines()

    # Find the number of vertices contained
    num_vertices = int(contents[1].strip().split(' ')[0])

    # Convert all the vertex lines to a list of lists
    vertex_list = [map(float, contents[i].strip().split(' ')) 
                    for i in range(2, 2+num_vertices)]

    # Return the vertices as a 3 x N numpy array
    return np.array(vertex_list).transpose(1,0)
```

Here are two examples of .off files. The first is correctly formatted:

```
OFF
5 0 0
-12.280500 26.701300 10.653150
-12.575700 26.313400 11.003550
-12.569100 26.309300 10.653150
-13.208100 25.441200 10.653150
-12.569100 26.309300 10.653150
```

and the second is incorrectly formatted:

```
OFF5 0 0
-12.280500 26.701300 10.653150
-12.575700 26.313400 11.003550
-12.569100 26.309300 10.653150
-13.208100 25.441200 10.653150
-12.569100 26.309300 10.653150
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the vertices from either format like:

```
# Find the number of vertices contained
if contents[0].strip().lower() != 'off':
    num_vertices = int(contents[0].strip()[3:].split(' ')[0])
    start_line = 1
else:
    num_vertices = int(contents[1].strip().split(' ')[0])
    start_line = 2

# Convert all the vertex lines to a list of lists
vertex_list = [map(float, contents[i].strip().split(' ')) 
                for i in range(start_line, start_line+num_vertices)]
```

Comment: Simple but effective. Thanks! I couldn't see the forest through the trees there...